# Match beginning of string and return value from seperate sheet or list, Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of mac addresses that i have to look up who the vendor is.  The first 6 characters are the only digits that matter and that are used to identify the vendor.  I would like to build a list on a separate sheet that I can reference so that if the first 6 characters of the 12 on the pulled mac address match the sheet it will return the value for the cell on the right.   So on the image below Columns A and B are my reference fields and Column D is the data to match and return the "answer" in column F.  The Reference field will be a lot bigger, maybe 100 lines or more.  I can leave the reference field on the same sheet if needed.

[image: Screen shot of simple verson]

Comment: so what is your question? did you put any effort on it? where did you stuck?

Comment: I am trying to find a formula that will match a column of Mac address (column D) to a list of macs (first 6 characters, Column A) and return the value from B to E.  I had tried Vlookup from the web and the suggestion below and I get #N/A response returned.  I have googled and searched this website as well.  Tried some matching forumula's with no luck as well.  I am thinking the main issue is matching a cell with 12 characters to a cell with only 6.  It is not feasible, that i am aware of, to lose the last 6, b/c i need those for record keeping/compliance purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Provided ColumnA is Text format and does not contain spaces and that ColumnD does not start with space/s or any hidden character/s:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(D2,8),A:B,2,0)
```

Comment: That returns a #N/A field

Comment: Also looking at maybe trying to utilize an API from a website

Comment: @KennyLunsford Then perhaps your `1st six` is really a date (time) data type and not text, as required and stated in the answer.

Comment: No i went back and made sure every field is set to Text.